# DotNet Core and a Net4.6.1 dependency

Tags: .net-core, kentico

Please forgive my ignorance here; I'll try to include as much detail as possible.

I wrote a dotnet core MVC website... I now find the need to access a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentico.Libraries/) written in net 4.6.1 otherwise I have to write a service layer to with all the CRUD operations myself.

Question: Is it possible to write a service layer that will do the work in net4.6.1 and return back JSON's to the dotnet core MVC website without writing a REST API?

I just need to be able to call a stand alone project and have it do the work and return the results.

Any ideas or direction would be helpful.

Comment: There are tons of libraries for .NET Core doing similar things, so I doubt why you want to stick to a .NET Framework only library. Besides, there should be .NET Core compatible beta already, https://www.kentico.com/product/roadmap

Answer (score 1):

If this is related to Kentico, Kentico 12 does not support .Net Core, but Kentico 2020 will.  You are a little ahead of the game i'm afraid : /